# Dotnetbar reference Errors In My Application After Re-Install

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbar

I have been using dotnetbar to make projects for a while now, but recentlyy i handed out my laptop to a friend of mine who happened to uninstall dotnetbar and then re-installed it with an older version (Had 12.8.0.6 Now 10.9)
After this happened I Could not open some projects because of reference based errors.
I tried 'Add Reference' options in VS 2013, but even after i re-select the dotnetbar references(which seem to have stuck to the version 12.8.0.6 rather than the one i have V 10.9) the errors still remain persistent and the reference selected remain unselected(after selecting them they seem good, but after going back to the add reference menu again, this references remain unchecked even after i had selected them earlier)
Images

What Control Panel Is Saying Is My Version
https://postimg.org/image/ugqy8wfkf/

LOG FILE:
http://pastebin.com/6z2Q8Cev

Please I Had worked so much on this project, and am due to hand it in on Monday
any help will be incredibly appreciated.

Thank You For Your Time.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok The solution is simply to remove all existing dotnetbar2.dll references and re-add them from your new installation folder